# pass value from extended template to base template in django

Tags: django, django-templates

In my project in `Django 2+`, I have created a `base.html` template which wraps the other content templates.

**base.html**

```
<html>
<head>
   <title>Example.com</title>
</head>

<body class="homepage">

    <!-- other HTML codes here -->

    {% block content %}

    {% endblock content %}

    <!-- other HTML codes here -->

</body>
</html>
```

and in one of content template

**pages/about.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}

    This is about page of example.com

{% endblock content %}
```

**Now, I have to change the class of `body` tag on `base.html` page to `aboutpage`**

**How can I pass the value `aboutpage` from content template to `base.html`?**

Comment: You have to write two separate body's  inside block content of individual html files. If you are changing the class of body although then their is no need to inherit it.

Comment: I can't write body in individual HTML files as there are other codes after body before content block. That way I would need to write all codes in individual files. Updated question to reflect code between `<body>` and content block

Answer (score 0):

In base generic template

```
<body class="{% block body_class %}{% endblock %}">
    <!-- other HTML codes here -->

{% block content %}

{% endblock content %}

<!-- other HTML codes here -->
</body>
```

Then in the child template, just define the block:

```
{% block body_class %} YOUR_CSS_CLASS {% endblock %}
```

This will give you

```
  <body class="YOUR_CSS_CLASS">...</body>
```

and you have to define this class in a linked CSS.

Comment: How can I check if class is empty, then print default class?